# Can't seem to get rid of giant footer

Tags: html, css

I have this page here:

http://www.cooperstandardperformance.com/content/test-blank-page

and I can't seem to get rid of the giant footer - there's no footer div or styling that I can see with Firebug that would indicate a giant footer.

I want the page to be white all down to the bottom - where am I going wrong? The only thing I can see that might be the cause is this:

```
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2B296A;
```

Is that right? Should I change that to #FFF; and be done with it? Or is there something else I am not noticing.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `background` style from your `body` tag.

Answer (score 1):

According to firebug, you have a background-color on the body tag in the stylesheet¹, on line 122 :

```
body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #001F3C;
  ...
}
```

¹ http://www.cooperstandardperformance.com/sites/all/themes/cooperstd/css/style.css?mr8j5a

Removing the background-color via firebug works.

Answer (score 0):

Give your `html` tag a background-color or remove the blue from the `body` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Don't provide any `styling` to `body` tag either through `id` or through `class`.
For eg.

```
<body>
//content goes here...
</body>
```

In your css:

```
body {
  background: #fff; 
  ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your div `content_column` does not stretch to the bottom of the page and its background color is a different color than you have set to your body background color. The "footer" you describe is not really a footer, it's just the rest of the page.

There are several ways to fix this. You can define the height of the `content_column` div to stretch to the bottom of the page, which becomes quite complicated due to compatibility issues. Or you can just set the body background color to the same as the `content_column` div or vise versa.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

http://www.cooperstandardperformance.com/sites/all/themes/cooperstd/css/style.css?mr8j5a
and here you will see..

```
`body {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #001F3C;
font-size: 1.4rem;
line-height: 2rem;
}`
```

here #001F3C is causing that the body to turn blue..

change **#001F3C to #FFFFFF**